# How to pass slash or some special characters in request mapping?

Tags: spring, rest, special-characters, path-variables, request-mapping

I want to pass slash and some special characters (which are coming as a result of encryption) in the request mapping and in path variables. Please help me to resolve this issue.

For example: `/{empid}/{name}/` where `empid` is encrypted and has values like `a12/234`.

Comment: Just Base64 the empid

Comment: @Gandalf Thanks for the reply.. If i use base64, everytime im getting different values for the same string, then its not possible to decode back right

Comment: Nope, Base64 does not change the byte values, so you can Base64.encode then Base64.decode and get exactly what you had before.